# Firebase - Maximum number of documents fetched in one request?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firebase, is there a maximum number of documents that can be fetched in a single request from a given collection? I couldn't find the answer to that question anywhere online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All such limits are listed in the Firestore documentation on [quotas and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits).

If there is no limit mentioned for something there, that means there is no hard-coded limit on it.

---

There may be a practical limit though. For example: as loading a large number of documents means that some clients may run out of memory, or your user may run out of patience (given the bandwidth required).

Comment: @FuadEfendi, the limits that you stated look like they only apply to your security rules. I don't see any such limit for authenticated or admin requests.